# Setting a percentage margin-top with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have images of all different sizes, some are landscape some are portrait.
I want to constantly change the margin-top to make the image sit perfectly in the center of the screen when I show the image in a lightbox .

I would really like to use a % for my margin because then it will look good on all size screens.

I used the code:

`$('img').css("margin-top",10%);`

but the computer doesn't seem to like the percentage value. It works fine if I use a pixel value. Any ideas on how I could get a percentage margin set through jQuery.

Comment: try using $('img').css("margin-top",'10%');

Answer (score 1):

The percentage should be passed as a string, like so:

```
$('img').css("margin-top","10%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute center css, DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/cda1knzq/

Resize the result frame and see, no matter how, it will be in center.

#### CSS

```
.absolute-center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

*Give this class to the element you want to make center, eg: div, img, etc...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center your image vertically then,use this:-

css:-

```
img{ top:50%; position:absolute;}
```

Jquery:-

```
var m_top = $('img').height()/2
$('img').css('margin-top','-' + m_top + 'px');
```

Comment: The effect can also be achieved using Yeyene's answer if you are working with images only...